# Inconsistent result of mktime in C

Tags: c

In various numerical experiments, I have seen that the *first* invocation of `mktime` changes the result in a bad way. As you can see, the first result in the loop if off by one hour while the others are fine. What is my mistake?

See this MWE:

```
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        // Set timestamp
        char timestamp[16] = "Feb 27 00:00:19";
        // Get local time
        time_t rawtime;
        struct tm * timeinfo;
        time(&rawtime);
        timeinfo = localtime (&rawtime);
        // Interpret time string
        struct tm querytime;
        // Expected format: Mmm dd hh:mm:ss
        // %b = Abbreviated month name
        // %e = Day of the month, space-padded ( 1-31)
        // %H = Hour in 24h format (00-23)
        // %M = Minute (00-59)
        // %S = Second (00-59)
        strptime(timestamp, "%b %e %H:%M:%S", &querytime);
        // Year is missing in aboves string - add the current year
        querytime.tm_year = (*timeinfo).tm_year;


        int unixtime = (int)mktime(&querytime);
        printf("%i - %s - %s\n",unixtime, timestamp, asctime(&querytime));
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Result:

```
gcc test.c && ./a.out 
1488146419 - Feb 27 00:00:19 - Sun Feb 26 23:00:19 2017

1488150019 - Feb 27 00:00:19 - Mon Feb 27 00:00:19 2017

1488150019 - Feb 27 00:00:19 - Mon Feb 27 00:00:19 2017
```

My timezone is `CET`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As so often, I found the problem shortly after summarizing everything for StackOverflow. The issue is that I didn't properly initialize the `struct tm`. If I change the corresponding line of code to

```
struct tm querytime = { 0 };
querytime.tm_isdst  = -1; // See comment below
```

then the issue goes away:

```
gcc test.c && ./a.out 
1488150019 - Feb 27 00:00:19 - Mon Feb 27 00:00:19 2017

1488150019 - Feb 27 00:00:19 - Mon Feb 27 00:00:19 2017

1488150019 - Feb 27 00:00:19 - Mon Feb 27 00:00:19 2017
```

I will leave this here for future reference.

Note that initializing all quantities with `0` turned out to cause problems with daylight saving time (DST). According to ISO/IEC 9899:TC3, `tm_isdst`, should be initialized with a negative value as `tm_isdst = 0` translates into `DST = No` instead of the intended `DST = Unknown`.

Comment: Funny, the first thing I thought when I saw the one hour difference was "does it perhaps have anything to do with DST?"

Comment: That seems likely but it isn't the case. Just by chance, Germany is away from UTC by one hour in the winter. The DST issue comes above that in addition.